# Custom source which can pump data from a ByteQueue

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

Crypto++ has a StringSource, ArraySource, FileSource, etc.

But I need to use source class which can fetch data from ByteQueue for future pass to filter and sink.

i.e.:

```
 _QUEUE_Source( MyPreparedQueue, true,
     new HashFilter(hash,
         new FileSink(zOutputFile),
         true));
```

How can I do that, w/o of sending MyPreparedQueue to additional intermediate memory buffer and choice of ArraySource?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use source class which can fetch data from ByteQueue for future pass to filter and sink...

[Source classes](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_source.html) can extract data and pump it to a filter. Your `_QUEUE_Source` should derive from [`Source`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_source.html). A `Source` is just a [`BufferedTransformation`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_buffered_transformation.html) ***with*** an attachment interface.

`MyPreparedQueue` can inherit from a [`ByteQueue`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_byte_queue.html). If you look at the inheritance diagram, `ByteQueue` inherits from `BufferedTransformation`. Or, `MyPreparedQueue` can inherit from [`Filter`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_filter.html) or `BufferedTransformation`.

Once you work out the missing functions for these two declarations:

```
QueueSource : public Source { ... }
PreparedQueue : public Filter { ... }
```

For the filter, you only need to implement `Put2`.

---

The Crypto++ wiki has some light reading on filters. See [Filters](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Filter) and [Filter (Intermediate)](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Filter_%28Intermediate%29).